# jsoup in a service android

Tags: android, service, jsoup

I have a service where I need that Jsoup connect to an URL, and the service will launched whit a AlarmManager; where the alarmManager launch the service, and the app closes

in my service I got this code inside an AsyncTask

```
Document document = null;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements paragraph = document.select("p");
            String text = paragraph.text();
```

And in the manifest I got

```
<service android:name="com.example.program.serviceprogram"
                android:process=":remote"></service>
```

Somebody Knows why the application is closes when Jsoup is executed in the service?

Comment: Including the log output would be useful.

Comment: with the emulator the not closes, adn I don't Know why, but in my tablet, the app closes

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the developer mode(USB debugging) in your tablet and connect that as a test device instead of virtual device. Then you'll get the exception trace and could find the root cause from that.

You can find more details on
http://www.developer.com/ws/android/connecting-your-android-device-to-eclipse.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/connecting-physical-android-devices-to-your-development-machine--mobile-12376